# WSO2 gives 413 (Request Entity Too Large) error for multipart file

Tags: api, tomcat, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have WSO2 configured. My **APIs are secured with WSO2 API manager**. When I try to upload multipart file of size less than 1mb, it works. But for file of **size greater than 1mb**, it gives **413 (Request Entity Too Large)** error. I tried to change file size limit in tomcat(web.xml) of WSO2 but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you calling the server directly or via some LB?

Comment: @BHA I have Nginx configured between API & WSO2. When I skip WSO2 and call API server directly from Nginx server then it works, but with WSO2 it doesnt.

Comment: I am also facing the same challenge, is there any solution for it. I am not using Nginx server.